# protoc-gen-docs 'protoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, command-line

Hello i need to install 'protoc-gen-docs' [protoc-gen-docs](https://github.com/pseudomuto/protoc-gen-doc) as part of my work, required to document proto files as html, I have followed the instructions but i can not even run the most simple of commands 'protoc' I think it may be a PATH variable error ?

I used the **go get** method as i do not have docker on my work computer and it successfully downloaded-*installed* the files as i can view them in my file browser, but i have no idea what to do next i have never used **go get**. I used this tutorial to install **go get** [go_get](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/setting-up-go-programming-language-on-windows-f02c8c14e2f/) and that had no issues, and i can run the test 'hello.exe' from CMD fine.

So any how i used **go get** to install protoc-gen-docs as it details, but no joy after the install, the commands do not work and to be honest i am unsure if i entered to command correctly? Heres is my attempt..

protoc --doc_out=./C:\Users\emartin\Desktop\proto_output --doc_opt=html,index.html proto/*.C:\Users\emartin\Desktop\test_proto_files

Resulting in the error:

> 'protoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I think i may need to have my files/folders in the same location as the protoc.exe ? but still i try just **protoc** in CMD and i get the same error, what must i add to my environmental paths ? and is there anything else i am doing wrong please?

EDIT:
I have now installed Docker and ran the test command **docker version** and **docker run hello-world** both run fine but i can not run the command to build an example file which is included with the install.

```
docker run --rm \
  -v $(pwd)/examples/doc:/out \
  -v $(pwd)/examples/proto:/protos \
  pseudomuto/protoc-gen-doc
```

I.E.

```
C:\Users\emartin>docker run --rm \ -v $(pwd)/examples/doc:/out \ -v 
$(pwd)/examples/proto:/protos \ pseudomuto/protoc-gen-doc
```

> docker: invalid reference format.
>   See 'docker run --help'.

**update 2:**
Removed the forward slashes between arguments ?

```
C:\Users\emartin>docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/examples/doc:/out -v 
$(pwd)/examples/proto:/protos pseudomuto/protoc-gen-doc
```

> docker: Error response from daemon: create $(pwd)/examples/doc:
>   "$(pwd)/examples/doc" includes invalid characters for a local volume
>   name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to
>   pass a host directory, use absolute path. See 'docker run --help'.

Removed the $(pwd)

```
C:\Users\emartin>docker run --rm -v /examples/doc:/out -v 
/examples/proto:/protos pseudomuto/protoc-gen-doc
```

> protos/*.proto: No such file or directory

**Third try:**

```
C:\Users\emartin>docker run --rm -v C:\Users\emartin\Desktop/examples/doc:/out -v 
 C:\Users\emartin\Desktop/examples/proto:/protos pseudomuto/protoc-gen-doc
```

> google/api/annotations.proto: File not found.
>
> github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators/validator.proto: File not found.
>
> Booking.proto: Import "google/api/annotations.proto" was not found or had errors.
>
> Booking.proto: Import "github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators/validator.proto" was not found or had errors.

I have docker running and i am logged in, what am i doing wrong ??? :(

Comment: Looks like you installed the docker image so you need to run docker to use it. See [pseudomuto/protoc-gen-doc: Documentation generator plugin for Google Protocol Buffers](https://github.com/pseudomuto/protoc-gen-doc)

Comment: Ok i just tried using Docker after installing it with permission from work and i can get the version run the hello-world and list its content fine, now i get an error with the default test command to build an example file: C:\Users\emartin>docker run --rm \ -v $(pwd)/examples/doc:/out \ -v $(pwd)/examples/proto:/protos \ pseudomuto/protoc-gen-doc
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.